How to correctly make a 'rebinning' of a .fits file?
The thing is i'm working with two .fits images, but the pixscale of each one is different.
Let's say Image 1 has a
CDELT = +- 0.0013888888888889 [deg] 

and Image 2 has a
 CDELT = +- 0.00277778000000 [deg]

So, in order to do accurate work with them, I need Image 1 to match de pixscale of Image 2. I'm not an expert on this stuff, but from what I could find I read that this is called 'rebinning'.
I have tried codes that I've found online or IA since I'm just a beginner and have zero idea of how to do it myself.
But it seems like it's not working because the data always get messed up and the plots of it doesn't make any sense. Also the resulting file is way larger than the original and I don't think that's right since I'm lowering the resolution of it.
Does anybody know how to do this properly and without affecting my data?
The last code I've tried is this one:
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
from astropy.io import fits

# Load the data from the second image
ha_hdul = fits.open('ha_image.fits')
ha_data = ha_hdul[0].data
ha_header = ha_hdul[0].header

# Calculate the rebinning factors
scale_factor_x = 0.00277778000000 / 0.0013888888888889
scale_factor_y = 0.00277778000000 / 0.0013888888888889

# Rebin the data using zoom
rebinned_ha_data = zoom(ha_data, (scale_factor_y, scale_factor_x), order=1)

# Update the WCS information
ha_header['CDELT1'] = -0.00277778000000
ha_header['CDELT2'] = 0.00277778000000

# Create a new PrimaryHDU object with the rebinned data and updated header
rebinned_ha_hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(rebinned_ha_data, header=ha_header)

# Save the rebinned image to a new FITS file
rebinned_ha_hdu.writeto('rebinned_ha_image.fits', overwrite=True)```


Have a look at https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ .

The CDELTi header keywords are part of the World Coordinate System (WCS) which describes how to map one set of coordinates to another. Typically this is used to map x,y pixel coordinates in an image to Right Ascension, Declination (RA, Dec) on the sky (but this is not the only coordinate system, number of dimensions or use). Crucially, unlike regular 2d images which scipy.ndimage is used to dealing with, there is no assumption in FITS data and WCS that the pixel and sky axes are aligned or linearly related to each other. RA may be aligned with the x-axis of the image but it almost always isn't and even if it is, it won't be perfect and there will be some rotation.
CDELTi (where i is the axis number, normally 1 or 2) is the scale in degrees/pixel but the sign also tells you the orientation as to which direction the value is increasing. Assuming one CDELT value means assuming the image scale is the same in each axis, which even with square CCD pixels, is not necessarily a good assumption as the optics (telescope, camera, etc) that produced the image may not produce the same scale in each direction. The other problems are rotation, which will be specified by a CROTAi keyword if the FITS header is using CDELT notation or a 2x2 CDi_j matrix otherwise (and which allows for skew to be included; general info in this paper) and potentially distortions specified by PVi_j keywords or with SIP polynomials (e.g. here).
By treating the FITS image data as a regular, aligned, linear 2D image and picking an average scale factor, this ignores the rest of the information in the WCS header about the transformation and doesn't deal with resampling the pixel information to a new non-aligned grid in a way that prevents aliasing and more importantly, preserves the astronomical flux in the images and combines it in a way to make meaningful measurements. As suggested by @9769953, it's highly recommended you look at astronomy-specific tools such as reproject, SWarp and Montage that will handle all of the details and complexities of the WCS mapping and doesn't assume 1 or 2 constant scale factors.
